# Swift bridging returns parent class object instead of derived class

Tags: objective-c, swift

Lets suppose I have a class in Objective C, via bridging I want to use in my swift project.

```
@implementation MyClass

+ (instancetype)startVideo:(NSInt *)videoName
{
    return [[MyClass alloc] initWithName:videoName
                              offset:@"0"]

}

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name 
               offset:(NSString *)offset
{

    self = [super init];

    return self;
}
```

Now there are two constructors will be available in the swift version after bridging

```
class MyClass{
    public convenience init!(videoName: String!)
    public init(name: String!, offset: String)
}
```

I derive class from MyClass in my swift project

```
class MyClass2 : MyClass{
    var purposeOfClass: String = "Child class"
}
```

Create an object of MyClass2 using convenience method

```
var obj = MyClass2("Swift.mov")
print(obj.purposeOfClass) // You will get exception at this point, because the constructor returned Parent's class object.
```

Here my question is why the bridging conversion make the static method initializer convenience initializer if the derived class return object can't be checked.

Answer (score 0):

In a Swift `init` method the truncated parameter name from Objective-C

```
 - (instancetype)initWithFoo:(NSString *)foo
```

to Swift

```
  init(foo : String)
```

is mandatory. You have to write

```
let obj = MyClass2(videoName:"Swift.mov")
print(obj.purposeOfClass)
```